# CyanogenMod compile error on OpenSuse

Tags: android, c++, linux

I'm trying to compile CM7.1 on my OpenSuse 11.4 64-bit. I think i've all the required packages in place, except for gcc-multilib and g++-multilib (couldnt find those for SuSe)

So, when i compile, i get some strange glibc errors -

```
*** glibc detected *** make: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000007a00340 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x733b6)[0x7ff37f2ad3b6]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6c)[0x7ff37f2b22dc]
```

All instructions online are for Ubuntu - there's no hard requirement for Ubuntu, right?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, got it. Was a problem with make 3.82 - reverted to 3.81, and it works now.

Described here - http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting/browse_thread/thread/7666e7f8271e1260